# Find difference between JSON data & update the difference

Tags: node.js, json, algorithm, sorting, differentiation

I've been stuck for hours, and I need your help.

The requirement is this.

Having two JSON objects, one is always the `source` and has all the data we need. 
Second JSON object does not contain **all** data from `source`

The requirement:

**This is the source JSON object.**

```
{
  "lang": "en",
  "global": {
    "clear_search": "Clear Search",
    "filter": "Filter",
    "projects": {
        "sort_projects": "Sort projects by"
    },
  },
}
```

And this is the second object (NOTE: First object always contains more data):

```
{
  "lang": "de",
  "global": {
    "clear_search": "Suche löschen",
    "filter": "Filter",
  },
}
```

I need to:

- Find difference between the `source` and object 2
- Update the difference, from `source` to object 2
- If property of the `source` is an Object, loop through it, which
  means if it's nested I need to loop through it, (recursion).
- If keys are the same, but values are not, keep the keys but use the
  object 2 value.

  Result:

```
{
  "lang": "de",
  "global": {
    "clear_search": "Suche löschen",
    "filter": "Filter",
    "projects": {
        "sort_projects": "Sort projects by"
    },
  },
}
```

Thank you for checking this out, I kindly ask you not to post code with the variable names, like `x` or `_`.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent a json in form of a tree. Every node in the tree will represent a json key. A parallel dfs from root for both the trees will help you mark the keys common to both the trees. The unmarked keys will be the difference.

You can extend this dfs traversal to further populate second json with the missing keys.

Comment: Something like a binary tree? I've pretty much solved this problem but the issue is when I have nested object, and in a nested object same set of keys, it doesn't add up a key, in a nested parent, but it writes one level before.

Comment: Not necessarily a binary tree. A node in a binary tree has two children, but in your case it can have multiple children. So just a normal tree. You can maintain a vector inside your node to maintain adjacency list.

Comment: Do you have any example? Thanks.